# Force.com Site Loginpage Redirect to Visualforce page

Tags: force.com-sites

I am creating a Force.com Site in there i ensure the login page as custom visualforce loginpage.Using this login page i use the partnerportal profile user credentials after the login will be success it doesn't redirect to the particular visualforce page it moves to Site Authorization Required page.I assign all pages to the partnerportal profiel but?Is there any possibilities to redirect to the particular visualforce page?

Comment: please share some code, are you passing the redirect page to Site.login ? Are the objects used on the new page available to portal?

Comment: Is the controller and VF page available for to the site?

Comment: have you tried to include your visual force page in your guest user profile?